# Postfix server stopped sending external email

Tags: macos, email, postfix-mta

We have a postfix server running on MAC.  Sometime yesterday our server stopped sending external email.  We can send and receive internally, and we can receive from external.  When we sent emails to other domains, though, they just disappear...

We've been working on this all day with no luck...  Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks!
--Charles

Here is our postconf -n

```
biff = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix
content_filter =
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /Library/Server/Mail/Data/mta
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
enable_server_options = yes
header_checks =
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
imap_submit_cred_file = /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/submit.cred
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps =
mail_owner = _postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = dovecot
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 20971520
mydestination =
mydomain = ourdomain.com
mydomain_fallback = localhost
myhostname = relay.ourdomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16 [::1]/128 [2001:240:587::]/64
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/system_user_maps
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = _postdrop
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_sasl_password_maps =
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit
smtpd_enforce_tls = no
smtpd_helo_required = no
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_pw_server_security_options = cram-md5,digest-md5,login,plain
smtpd_recipient_limit = 1000
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/certificates/relay.ourdomain.com.028E0388CA5957E50A13248BAD1711F41C84F596.chain.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/certificates/relay.ourdomain.com.028E0388CA5957E50A13248BAD1711F41C84F596.cert.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = SSLv2, aNULL, ADH, eNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/certificates/relay.ourdomain.com.028E0388CA5957E50A13248BAD1711F41C84F596.key.pem
smtpd_use_pw_server = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
use_sacl_cache = yes
virtual_alias_domains = $virtual_alias_maps hash:/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps hash:/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/virtual_users
postconf: warning: /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix//main.cf: unused parameter: default_destination_recipient_limit:=1000
relay:~ localadmin$
```

Comment: Please post the log lines generated by postfix when you send an email to some external domains.

Comment: @clement: Oddly enough, the log was not showing anything when sending emails.  It is only showing when users do not authenticate properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was being caused by a typo...

I kept getting the error:

```
unused parameter: default_destination_recipient_limit
```

Upon looking at the master.cf file, I found that it had:

```
default_destination_recipient_limit: = 1000
```

Note the colon in that line.  Fixed an the issue has gone away.